# ajax in jsp call sql query when select dropdown value

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

need help to get value from sql table in jsp when select from dropdown.

when i select CL then I want to run a query in jsp get all record from sql table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $leavetype=  $('.leavetype');
    $leavetype.change(function (){
        var value =  $('.leavetype').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "applicationformuser.jsp", //this is my servlet
            data: {leavetype : value},
                success: function(msg){      
                    alert(msg.data);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="leavetype" name="leavetype"style="position:absolute;margin-left:160px;margin-top:160px;height:30px;width:300px;">
    <option value="CL">CL</option>
    <option value="ML">ML</option>
    <option value="SL">SL</option>
    <option value="EL/PL">EL/PL</option>
    <option value="CPL">CPL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How is this Java?

Comment: I am using JSP call ajax.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select class="leavetype" name="leavetype" style="position:absolute;margin-left:160px;margin-top:160px;height:30px;width:300px;" onchange="GetAllDetails(this.value);">
        <option value="CL">CL</option>
        <option value="ML">ML</option>
        <option value="SL">SL</option>
        <option value="EL/PL">EL/PL</option>
        <option value="CPL">CPL</option>
    </select>


  function GetAllDetails(value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "applicationformuser.jsp", //this is my servlet
            data: { leavetype: value },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.data);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: how can pass value in jsp to excutequery with selected value.

Comment: am not a java developer @MonikaRawat.if you have any doubt in jquery,can you please ask that.

Answer (score 0):

You `ajax` code works fine,you just need to get it in jsp code, you can get parameter using `request.getParameter()`:

```
<% 
String leavetype = request.getParameter("leavetype");//after get value,you can pass it to query sql.
%>
```